# Why the type inference failed of inline method?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3

I have following codes, where the `f1` works but the `f2` compile fails.
Is there any tricks to make `f2` works too without using `Schema[T]` like?
[Run It here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dO8CEOysR1uJlNYcuREpzg)

```
trait Base

trait Schema[T <: Base]:
    given Schema[T] = this

class Sub1 extends Base

object Sub1 extends Schema[Sub1]

class Sub2 extends Base

object Sub2 extends Schema[Sub2]

trait Container[T <: Base]

object Container:
    import scala.compiletime.erasedValue

    object C1 extends Container[Sub1]
    object C2 extends Container[Sub2]

    def f1[T <: Base : Schema]: Container[T] = summon[Schema[T]] match
        case Sub1 => C1
        case Sub2 => C2

    inline def f2[T <: Base]: Container[T] = inline erasedValue[T] match
        case _: Sub1 => C1
        case _: Sub2 => C2
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed the signature a bit, and came up with this:

```
type Cout[T <: Base] = T match
    case Sub1 => Container[Sub1]
    case Sub2 => Container[Sub2]

inline def f2[T <: Base]: Cout[T] = inline erasedValue[T] match 
    case _: Sub1 => C1
    case _: Sub2 => C2
```

And it compiles (and runs) just fine.

### What?

Seems kind of weird, I don't have much experience in Scala3, and my consumptions may not be correct in some cases, but the implementation of `f2` makes perfect sense to me. The second weird thing is that when I change the definition of `Cout` to `type Cout[T <: Base] = Container[T]`, which (to us) is basically the same thing (but not to the compiler), everything breaks with the same error, and the error is that `Required Container[T], found C1.type`. I struggled with it a bit, and shamelessly used `asInstanceOf` on `Container` objects:

```
inline def f2[T <: Base]: Container[T] = inline erasedValue[T] match 
  case _: Sub1 => C1.asInstanceOf[Container[Sub1]]
  case _: Sub2 => C2.asInstanceOf[Container[Sub2]]
```

And the exact same error occurred. But when I do:

```
inline def f2[T <: Base]: Container[T] = inline erasedValue[T] match 
  case _: Sub1 => C1.asInstanceOf[Container[T]]
  case _: Sub2 => C2.asInstanceOf[Container[T]]
```

As you can guess, everything is fine again. I guess the compiler cannot prove that `Container[T]` is the same as `Container[Sub1]` in the first branch, and the same thing for the second branch.

While it seems like a bug to me, yet I'm not sure if this is a bug, but in my opinion, just like the implementation of `f1`, the compiler should be able to infer `T` in the match arms, and conclude that `C<N>.type (Container[Sub<N>])` is `Container[T]` when `T = Sub<N>`.